# Using Sol2 to expose an interface to Lua and implementing the method in Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I am using the sol2 library to create a set of C++ class wrappers. About 10 years ago, I did the same with luabind and, as far as I remember, it was quite straightforward.

However, now I want to use sol2, since the other one seems abandoned.

So, what I want to do is:

Define an abstract class in C++
Create another class, and in this class, I would have a method that takes instances of classes that implement the interface.
In a method of this same class, be able to call the abstract method, which will point to the Lua implementation.
I'm not quite sure if I'm making a mistake in the Lua code, but I remember this being possible.

Lua code:

```lua
local Actor = setmetatable({}, {__index = loopable})

function Actor:new()
    local obj = {}
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end

function Actor:loop()
    print("Actor:loop") -- It should print this on `e:run()`
end

local a = Actor:new()

local e = engine:new()
e:add_loopable(a)
e:run()
```

Where `loopable` is my abstract class.

C++ sol2 code:

```
lua.new_usertype<engine>("engine",
                        "add_loopable", &engine::add_loopable,
                        "run", &engine::run);

// I do not know how to declare a abstract class.
lua.new_usertype<loopable>("loopable",
                            "loop", &loopable::loop);
```

Minimal reproducible example: https://godbolt.org/z/6n71v3Pq3

Comment: Your Lua VM does not have `setmetatable` global variable.  Something is wrong with Lua VM initialization.  Try to run successfully minimal Lua program `print(setmetatable)` - it must print non-nil value.

Comment: Start by opening the base library: `lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);`